# Changing var variables to val

Tags: scala, var

I have this piece of code

```
object Sudoku extends SudokuLikeGame {
  type T = Board

  def parse(str: String): Board = { 
      // helper method to filter out whether or not the coordinate given is mapped for one 
      // value and then must check for the rest of the peers
      def parseHelper(board: Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]], 
                      row: Int, col: Int): Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]] = {
        var parseBoard = board
        val oldValues = parseBoard(row, col).head//takes the first value 
        for(r <- 0 to 8; c <- 0 to 8){
          //iterates the list of peers from peers() and if at the row and col has a value 
          //contained within the board passed in
          for {(r, c) <- Solution.peers(row, col)
               if (parseBoard(r, c).contains(oldValues))} { 
            //removes all the old values from 
            val newValue = parseBoard(r, c) diff List(oldValues)
            //removes all the old values at the coord r, c and maps it to the correct value
            parseBoard = (parseBoard - ((r, c))) + ((r, c) -> newValue) 
            if(newValue.size == 1)  //one value means no more peers
              parseBoard = parseHelper(board, r, c)  
        }
      }
      parseBoard
    }

    var sudokuBoard = Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]]()
    if(str.length == 81){
      str
    }
    else{
      println("insuffient length")
      System.exit(1)
    }
```

I have written some var variables. I know that these are mutable variables. However, I was told that I cannot use these var in my assignment. 
It doesn't seem that I can simply change them to val, because val is an immutable reference and I am reassignimg the value of the var.

So how would I be able to change these var variables to val? Would I have to re-think the structure if my code?

Comment: Your `for` can become a `foldLeft`, where you pass as the accumulator the current value of parseBoard. That would allow you to avoid a mutable `parseBoard`

Comment: Also, I  think there's a bug - your outer loop iterates over the board, but you never use the values of  `r` and `c`  - they're shadowed by the ones in your inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it (untested since we're missing some stuff from your code, and taking a guess at what `Solution.peers` does). Instead of modifying `parseBoard` we use `foldLeft` (twice) to pass down the new board to the next step

```
 def peers(row:Int, col:Int) = {
    val rs = for (r <- 0 to 8 if r != row) yield (r, col)
    val cs = for (c <- 0 to 8 if c != col) yield (row, c)
    rs ++ cs
    } 
  val cells = for (r <- 0 to 8; c <- 0 to 8)  yield (r,c)


def parseHelper(board: Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]],
              row: Int, col: Int): Map[(Int, Int), List[Int]] = {
  val oldValues = board((row, col)).head //takes the first value
  cells.foldLeft(board) {
  case (b1, (r, c)) =>
    //iterates the list of peers from peers() and if at the row and col has a value
    //contained within the board passed in
    peers(row, col).foldLeft(b1) {
      case (b, (r, c)) =>

        if (b((r, c)).contains(oldValues)) {
          //removes all the old values from
          val newValue = b((r, c)) diff List(oldValues)
          //removes all the old values at the coord r, c and maps it to the correct value
          if (newValue.size == 1) parseHelper(board, r, c) else b - ((r, c)) + ((r, c) -> newValue)
        } else b
    }
  }
}
```